# how to call service method from object property in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Angular Js Object:

```
$scope.Global = {
    brand: null,
    group: null,
    timeperiod: null,
    gender: $scope.Gender[0],
    segmenttype: $scope.SegmentType[0]
};
```

Angular Js Service method:

```
dataFactory.getAllTimePeriods().success($scope.handleSuccess).then(function (result) {
        $scope.TimePeriods = result.data;
    });
```

is it possible that we can call service method to object property?

like this

```
$scope.Global = {
    brand: null,
    group: null,
    timeperiod:   dataFactory.getAllTimePeriods().success($scope.handleSuccess).then(function (result) {
        $scope.TimePeriods = result.data;
    });,
    gender: $scope.Gender[0],
    segmenttype: $scope.SegmentType[0]
};
```

Comment: why don't you call it afterward and just update it's value?

Comment: I can do that but by that time I am calling one service method which requires Global parameters and it finds null.

Comment: what about setting all global object only when the response is success?

Comment: @parthicool05 : how? I am getting error.

Comment: hi I will send the sample wait friend...

Comment: @parthicool05 please help me with fiddle need it asap. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Liad Livnat said you could write

```
dataFactory.getAllTimePeriods().success($scope.handleSuccess).then(function (result) {
    $scope.Global = {
        brand: null,
        group: null,
        timeperiod: result.data;
        gender: $scope.Gender[0],
        segmenttype: $scope.SegmentType[0]
    };
}
```

If you have multiple promises you can use $q.all like this

```
var promiseOne = dataFactory.getAllTimePeriods().success($scope.handleSuccess);
var promiseTwo = ...
var promiseThree = ...
$q.all([promiseOne, promiseTwo, promiseThree])
  .then(function(results) {

    $scope.Global = {
        brand: null,
        group: null,
        timeperiod: results[0].data;
        gender: $scope.Gender[0],
        segmenttype: $scope.SegmentType[0]
    };

    console.log(results[0], results[1], results[2]);
});
```

As you can see the results variable gets all the data from the promises in an array and you can access them using results[0], results[1], and so on.

Comment: what if I have 30 35 properties and each values comes from service?